# Calling an Action Result through my ajax call and re-posting it after success on a new window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I must be doing something wrong:

I have the following controller that is being called from this ajax call. Once it is posted successfully I would like to process to a partial view that open to a new window. Not sure what I'm missing in my window.open url on my ajax call...

Here is my razor page:

```
     @model myModel 
     {
     var myNewControllerViewStoreDataURL = Url.Action("MyNewController", "Routing", new { area = 
     "Routing" });

    var showMapView = function (targetDay, targetRoute) {
    let serviceIds = getServiceIdsForDayAndRoute(targetDay, targetRoute);
    if (serviceIds.length > 0) {
        var data = {
            "serviceIds": serviceIds,
            "scheduleDate": formatDateTime(targetDay),
            "route": targetRoute
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.Success) {
                        let showMapUrl = **I would like to just stay
                         window.open(showMapUrl);
```

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult MyNewView(string route, DateTime scheduleDate){

    ...Code....

    var serviceIdsListTest = new List<int>();


    return partialView("MyNewView", new MyNewViewModel(LoggedInUser.CultureInfo, routeType, 
    SchedulerMapParams.ScheduledDate, serviceCodeHtmlColors, stopsForServicesErrorResult.Result, 
    routingAssistantViewModel, haloLegendViewModel));
    }
```

Comment: what is the showMapUrl  here

Comment: /Routing/MyNewView  that is a razor page. Hope it make sense...

Comment: I don't want to make another call to my controller just process it to my partial view

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,it will fix your problem

```
  window.open('/Home/MyNewView', '_blank', 
  'left=100,top=100,width=400,height=300,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
```